# Filtering periods from first dataframe to a second dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, date, filter

This is the first data frame from which I want to take the in-between dates `Date on` and `Date off` in order to filter the second data frame:

**Dataframe #1**  rot_data_filter

```
      Period     SERIE    Date_on   Date_off Truck No rot
   1:      1 S8R005232 2019-07-31 2019-12-16      022-648
   2:      2 S8R005232 2020-01-20 2020-03-10      022-650
   3:      3 S8R005232 2020-03-10 2020-08-16      022-650
   4:      4 S8R005232 2021-02-23 2021-04-03      022-641
   5:      5 S8R005440 2019-07-31 2019-12-16      022-648
  ---                                                    
8405:   8405 B8JSG0282 2021-12-16 2022-02-23      022-740
8406:   8406 B8JSG0282 2022-02-28 2022-03-21      022-837
8407:   8407 B8KSG0231 2021-12-22 2022-03-17      022-828
8408:   8408 B8KSG0231 2022-03-17 2022-03-22      022-711
8409:   8409 B8KSG0231 2022-03-24 2022-07-07      022-711
```

**Dataframe #2** analysis

Now this is the second data frame which I want to apply the filter to `Date`:

```
          Date       Truck No   Shovel Empty travel distance Loaded travel distance
       1: 2019-06-30  022-915    E21     2572                   2572
       2: 2019-06-30  022-454    I16     7638                   4446
       3: 2019-06-30  022-484    E30     2074                   2428
       4: 2019-06-30  022-917    E27     2398                   2398
       5: 2019-06-30  022-427    Q04     2712                   3580
 ---                                                                        
4478010: 2022-07-31  022-850    E25      3795                   3762
4478011: 2022-07-31  022-458    I44      3176                    760
4478012: 2022-07-31  022-904    E27      5399                   5405
4478013: 2022-07-31  022-393    I41      4944                   4910
4478014: 2022-07-31  022-474    Q04      4889                   4907
```

This is what I've tried as of now , manually use `readline` to firstly filter out each period one by one from rot_data_filter and creating one data frame for each period (filter_date1,filter_date2.. filter_daten)

```
period <- readline(prompt = "Movement # period:")
1
Period_filter <- rot_data_filter %>% filter(Period==period)

filter_date1 <- analysis %>% filter(`Date`>= Period_filter$Date_on,
                                    `Date`<=Period_filter$Date_off,
                                    `Truck No`==Period_filter$`Truck No rot`) %>% 
  mutate(Serial=Period_filter$SERIE)
```

Output is like this for `Period filter`:

```
       SERIE    Date_on   Date_off
1: S8R005232 2019-07-31 2019-12-16
```

Then final output is like this for `filter_date1` after filtering `analysis` by using the `Period filter` `Date_on` and `Date off` and `mutate` adding the SERIE.

```
          Date    Truck No Shovel    Empty travel distance Loaded travel distance Serial
   1: 2019-08-03  022-648    I32                 18420                  20649 S8R005232
   2: 2019-08-03  022-648    C26                 25065                  16012 S8R005232
   3: 2019-08-03  022-648    C32                 12827                  12827 S8R005232
   4: 2019-08-03  022-648    C23                  1425                   1266 S8R005232
   5: 2019-08-03  022-648    C23                  1266                   1425 S8R005232
  ---                                                                                  
2355: 2019-12-16  022-648    C23                 24591                   8872 S8R005232
2356: 2019-12-16  022-648    C23                  8872                   7793 S8R005232
2357: 2019-12-16  022-648    Q02                  8786                  25283 S8R005232
2358: 2019-12-16  022-648    C29                 24664                  24902 S8R005232
2359: 2019-12-16  022-648    I36                 15264                  11792 S8R005232
```

I would like to get this output for each period without manually filtering them using the `readline` maybe a function or repeat loop lines can help?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please provide a sample of your two data sets, by using the output of the `dput()` command.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply do a non equi join.

```
analysis[rot_data_filter,
         on=.(`Truck No` = `Truck No rot`, Date>=Date_on, Date<=Date_off),
         nomatch=0
]
```

Comment: It would be helpful for testing to share data where there is actually a match. Right now i your example data, there are no trucks in `analysis` that are also in `rot_data_filter`